# TFS - 'Run SSH task' option times out

Tags: ssh, tfs, azure-devops

In TFS, Am using SSH task with 'Commands' option to connect to a remote machine and run a set of few commands. Am using cd to a particular folder and running a shell script using 'sh '

This script usually takes around 2 hours to finish execution. The ssh task timesout after 15 minutes and exits the task. But when I see in the machine manually, the process is running.

Why doesn't the ssh task wait until the script finishes completely

Comment: No there is no change. Its the same behavior. by default the timeout is set to 0

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you may encountered a time out limitation of SSH task or build definition.

First, please double check the time out setting under **control options**.

> Specifies the maximum time, in minutes, that a task is allowed to
>   execute before being cancelled by server. A zero value indicates an
>   infinite timeout.

[image]

Another place to check is **build job time out**, under the settings of your build definition: Option ->Build job timeout in minutes.

> Specifies the maximum time a build job is allowed to execute on an
>   agent before being canceled by the server.
>
> An empty or zero value indicates an infinite timeout.

[image]

If both set properly and you still get the time out, please attach more detail related build failed log with [Verbose Debug Mode](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/) by setting `system.debug=true` for troubleshooting.